# why doesn't LD_PRELOAD trick catch open() when called by fopen()?

Tags: linux, ld-preload

I use the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to catch `open64()` calls and I think I know how to do it correctly:  with the program `foobar` compiled from

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  open64("foobar.txt", 0);
  return 0;
}
```

I catch `open64` as I expect:

```
>LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/catch.so ./foobar
open64 called
```

However, when `open64` is replaced with `fopen64`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  fopen64("foobar.txt", "r");
  return 0;
}
```

now `open64` is not caught.  Why?

In case that `fopen64` calls `open`, I do have both `open` and `open64` intercepted, none is caught.

Both versions of the program `foobar`, when executed with `strace`, show that `open` is called, which means that `fopen64` does call internally `open` or `open64`.

I thought that perhaps something is statically linked, but that seems not the case:

```
>ldd foobar
```

shows

```
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
```

which is a shared library, and

```
>nm /lib64/libc.so.6
```

shows both `open64` and `fopen64` as defined (but not `fopen`, that's why in the question, I used the "64" versions for the purpose of argument; perhaps `fopen` is a macro to `fopen64` or something like that, does not matter, since the problem happens with or without 64).

Comment: What differences between the two do _ltrace_ [sic] and/or LD_DEBUG=all show you?

Comment: @pilcrow not sure what you mean...  I explained all of that above, `strace` shows `open(foobar.txt`... (and other irrelevant stuff), `LD_PRELOAD` shows nothing.

Comment: Having the same problem. Wondering what's going on.

Answer (score 11):

I think it works like this: user space programs call library functions in libc, and libc calls system calls in the kernel. With LD_PRELOAD it is possible to intercept libc calls between the program and libc. You can not intercept system calls. If glibc calls another function internally (e.g. fopen calls open), you can not intercept it.

Instead of using `strace`, it is better to use `ltrace` in this case because that shows which library calls are done. These are the calls that you can intercept.

[image]

Comment: OK, if I use `ltrace`, it just shows that my program is calling `fopen()` , that's all and I already know that.  So it's not helpful at all... `fopen()` must be calling `open()` or some such, or perhaps `syscall()` but these are not shown in `ltrace`, why, I am not sure, but it does not seem helpful...

Comment: what do you mean by "if fopen calls open, you cannot intercept it"? If `fopen` is defined in `libc` then yes I should be able to intercept `fopen` if I use `LD_PRELOAD` to load `libc`.  It does not matter what `fopen` is calling.  Please comment.

Comment: "it" in "you cannot intercept it" refers to `open`, not `fopen`. If `fopen` calls `open`, you cannot intercept `open`.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) with `PTRACE_SYSCALL`. Here's an [blog on it](https://blog.nelhage.com/2010/08/write-yourself-an-strace-in-70-lines-of-code/).

Comment: I read this blog post and I am not sure what you mean.... The blog describes how to use the function `ptrace()` to implement a simple version of command `strace`.  I don't need that - I am perfectly fine with the full version of `strace`, I used it as I showed above and it is showing that the system call `open` is used.  That is not what I want.  I want to know what the user function is that is calling that system call, is it `open()` or `open64()` and if so, then why can't I catch it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue recently, and I think the answer comes down to glibc's implementation.

The following is all AFAICT from looking at the glibc-2.37 source code and not to be taken as gospel.

fopen() and fopen64() end up eventually calling internal functions __open() (or, unlikely, __open_nocancel()) (perhaps with O_LARGEFILE) rather than open() or open64().  These low-level functions perform an inline system call rather than invoking the open() syscall wrapper (that you overrode with LD_PRELOAD) that does the same.

You might say, "Well, let's just override __open() with LD_PRELOAD and call it a day".  That would work, except that glibc also marks __open() and __open_nocancel() with __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))).  That causes these symbols to be invisible to LD_PRELOAD, so while you can define your own version of __open(), calls to the original __open() won't be intercepted properly.

I looked at Bionic (Android libc)'s source code for comparison and, while I think you could intercept open() like you wanted to, I think you would have problems on the fclose() end (because it eventually calls ___close(), which is hidden, instead of close()).